# Quando a senha ou o login estão errado a sessão não é fechada

Tags: php, session

Boa tarde, fiz uma programação de verificar se os dados do login estão errados ou não, quando eu coloco os dados errados ele me da um `alert` falando que o login ou a senha estão incorretos mas quando clico **ok** ele aparce outro `alert` falando que fiz login com sucesso e indo para outra página... o que está acontecendo?

codigo:

```
<html>

<head>
    <script src="../js/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/jqueryAtualizado.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/jqueryAtualizado.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <?php 
include("conexao.php");

if(isset($_POST['senha']) && strlen($_POST['login']) > 0){

    if(!isset($_SESSION))
        session_start();

    $_SESSION['login'] = $link -> escape_string($_POST['login']);
    $_SESSION['senha'] = $_POST['senha'];


    $sql_code = "SELECT senha, codigo FROM usuario WHERE login = '$_SESSION[login]'";
    $sql_query = $link -> query($sql_code) or die ($link -> error);
    $dado = $sql_query->fetch_assoc();
    $total = $sql_query-> num_rows;


    if($total == 0){
        echo "<script>alert('Login ou a senha estão errados.');</script>";
    }
    else{
        if($dado['senha'] == $_SESSION['senha']){

            $_SESSION['usuario'] = $dado['login'];

        }
    }

    if(count($total) != 0){
        echo "<script>alert('Login efetuado com sucesso.'); location.href='../Adm/AdmAgenda.php';</script>";
    }

}


?>
</body>

</html>
```

Obrigado...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A questão nem é a sessão ser fechada quando o login está errado, mas sim que ela não deveria nem mesmo ser definida caso o login estivesse errado. Ela só deveria passar a existir caso o login estivesse ok. Então, assim,você criaria ela.

O Ideal seria algo como:

```
$login = $_POST['login'];
$senha = $_POST['senha'];

$resultado = $bd->consultarLogin($login);

if ($resultado && $resultado['senha'] === $senha) {
      // Só aqui então é que a sessão seria criada

      $_SESSION['usuario'] = $resultado;
}
```

<sub>O código acima foi meramente ilustrativo, o que importa no final das contas é você entender a ideia.</sub>

Além do mais, seu código precisa de uma refatoração. Não faz sentido por exemplo usar `count` em `$total`já que ela é uma variável do tipo `int`.
Também tem código redundante.

Eu pensei em algo mais ou menos assim:

```
// Sempre lembre-se que session deve vir no topo do script, por precaução

if(!isset($_SESSION)) session_start();

include("conexao.php");

if(isset($_POST['senha']) && strlen($_POST['login']) > 0) {


    $login = $link -> escape_string($_POST['login']);
    $senha = $_POST['senha'];


    $sql_code = "SELECT senha, codigo FROM usuario WHERE login = '$login'";
    $sql_query = $link -> query($sql_code) or die ($link -> error);
    $dado = $sql_query->fetch_assoc();
    $total = $sql_query-> num_rows;


    if ($total == 0) {
        echo "<script>alert('Login ou a senha estão errados.');</script>";

    } elseif ($dado['senha'] == $_SESSION['senha']) {

        $_SESSION['usuario'] = $dado['login'];

        echo "<script>alert('Login efetuado com sucesso.'); location.href='../Adm/AdmAgenda.php';</script>";
    }

}
```

Note que eu evito colocar coisas na sessão antes de estar logado.

<sub>O código acima não está a oitava maravilha ainda, mas já a pra melhorar algumas redundâncias</sub>

Comment: Nossa, gostei deu uma boa diminuida no código... Obrigado funcionou so que se eu coloco qualquer senha ele entra kkkkk

Comment: Tem um erro de digitação no meu código. Ao invés de _SESSION[senha] deve ser $senha

Comment: estava tentando colocar `'usuario'`

Comment: Eu estou falando dá verificação do elseif

Comment: Sim sim, tinha visto que estava igual então coloquei `$dado['usuario'] == $_SESSION['senha']` e assim ia, mas poderia colocar qualquer senha que ele fazia o login